# How to change a number inside a cell to this smallest value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to change a number inside a cell to this smallest value. Example: inside A1 we have the value of 65238 & we would like to transform the value to become 23568 or also for the matter a string of characters: bgiead -> abdegi.

Comment: Do you have the algorithm? (unimplemented in vba)

Comment: Create an array based on the character length, iterate through the string placing each character into an element, sort the array, then loop through the array concatenating each value.  If the string has both letters and numbers, then it all depends on your expected output.

Comment: I don't ask for VBA I ask for a solution only with MACRO. Thank anyway

Comment: VBA is a Macro is VBA. It's different words for the same thing.

Comment: `Excel Macros` are created using the language called `VBA` (Visual basic for applications).  The tag [tag:macros] clearly states that it is not intended for use of Office applications if you read the description.

Comment: Now regarding your actual question.  Please explain where you are stuck trying to achieve a solution to this problem, _help us help you_

Comment: What I would like is to put a formula in a cell inside a spreadsheet. Not in trhough VBA. with VBA I know how to do it.

Comment: @user1626749 Well that would not be a `Macro` that would be a `Formula`

Comment: @user1626749 please then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30398002/edit) your question, removing the [tag:excel-vba] tag I put in and replace it with [tag:excel-formula] if that is what you desire

Comment: I don't know how to do that in Excel formula & perhaps it is not possible.

Comment: I sincerely doubt it's possible using just formulas; Excel's string functions aren't that sophisticated, and you would need all the values broken up into individual cells for range calculations to work.

Answer (score 0):

Subject to restrictions I think theoretically possible with just a formula but sorting characters in a cell with standard functions seems highly inadvisable. For example where the input (in A1) is known to be a three-digit number this should work:

```
=MIN(MID(A1,1,1),MID(A1,2,1),MID(A1,3,1))&MIN(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MIN(A1,MID(A1,1,1),MID(A1,2,1),MID(A1,3,1)),""),1,1),MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MIN(A1,MID(A1,1,1),MID(A1,2,1),MID(A1,3,1)),""),2,1))&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MIN(A1,MID(A1,1,1),MID(A1,2,1),MID(A1,3,1)),""),MIN(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MIN(A1,MID(A1,1,1),MID(A1,2,1),MID(A1,3,1)),""),1,1),MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MIN(A1,MID(A1,1,1),MID(A1,2,1),MID(A1,3,1)),""),2,1)),"")
```

The complexity would then rocket if to handle numbers of different lengths as well as strings of different lengths.

Certainly viable without say VBA however. For example, split Text to Columns -  Fixed width (single character spacing), sort with SMALL and then concatenate.